# "result type must be constructible from value type of input range" when trying to push stack<unique_ptr> (or deque) into a vector

Tags: c++

I essentially have something like this (I changed the variable names, sorry if it looks strange)

```cpp
#include <stack>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

struct Sequence {
    std::stack<std::unique_ptr<int>> numbers;
    // It works if I change it to this
    //std::stack<std::unique_ptr<int>, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>>> numbers; 
    Sequence(const std::vector<int> &v) {
        for (int i : v) {
            numbers.push(std::make_unique<int>(i));
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    // constructing alone works fine
    // Sequence s{{3, 1, 5}};   

    // but pushing it into a vector gives an error
    std::vector<Sequence> ts;
    ts.emplace_back(std::vector<int>{1, 5, 2});
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling gives this error:

```
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:137:72: error: static assertion failed: result type must be constructible from value type of input range
  137 |       static_assert(is_constructible<_ValueType2, decltype(*__first)>::value,
```

when I try to put a Sequence in a vector. If I change the underlying stack container from `std::deque` to `std::vector` however, it works. My guess is something to do with moving and copying `unique_ptr`, but I don't really understand the nuances -- does someone know what's going on?

Comment: Not sure why that doesnt work, here's what works: https://godbolt.org/z/ach9zn

Comment: Adding `Sequence(Sequence &&other) = default;` seems to make it work (?). I'd expect that a `vector<Sequence>` needs some way to copy/move a `Sequence` to allow for growth. (Copy is impossible though in this case). I don't remember the exact rules, but I'd guess that since you have specified a constructor, the move constructor is no longer automatically generated.

Comment: `std::stack<T, C>` defaults to `std::stack<T, std::deque<T>>`, and `std::deque<std::unique<ptr>>` doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This appears to be an instance of the old "move if noexcept" issue with `std::vector`. To be brief, `std::vector<Sequence>::push_back` may need to reallocate, and in such cases it will use the copy constructor of `Sequence` because it cannot prove that the move constructor will not throw an exception. In order to force it to use the move constructor, you have to mark the copy constructor of `Sequence` as deleted:

```
Sequence(const Sequence&) = delete;
Sequence(Sequence&&) = default;
```

This should make your code compile.

The reason why the issue disappears when the underlying container of the stack is changed, is that `std::vector` is noexcept movable, while `std::deque` may not be (and, in libstdc++, which you appear to be using, it is not). This noexcept-movability property is propagated by the containing `std::stack` and up to the implicit move constructor of `Sequence`. Thus, with an underlying `vector`, the `Sequence` advertises itself as noexcept-movable, and the enclosing `vector` does the right thing. With an underlying deque, the `Sequence` advertises itself as not-noexcept-movable, the enclosing `vector` instantiates the copy constructor, and the instantiation fails because it requires the copy constructor of a `unique_ptr`.

Comment: Just adding `Sequence(Sequence&& rhs) = default;` without explicitly `delete`ing the copy ctor works too.

Comment: @TedLyngmo That's true. It results in the deletion of the implicit copy constructor. This rule is obscure, so relying on it may confuse the next person who reads the code (possibly oneself).

Comment: True! `Sequence(Sequence&&) noexcept(false) = default;` also works ...

Comment: @puio Unfortunately, this is one of the cases where there's no obvious answer to how compiler writers can help diagnose the crux of the issue. So this is just one thing that C++ programmers will have to be aware of during the near future. However, eventually they should be able to make more containers noexcept, which would alleviate the issue (Jonathan Wakely mentioned that in the libstdc++ `std::deque` case, it requires an ABI break).

Comment: I'm trying this out ... I still don't get how adding a throwing move ctor can make it work though.

Comment: @TedLyngmo as we discussed further up the thread, a user-declared move constructor causes the copy constructor to be deleted. Once the copy constructor is deleted, the enclosing vector stops trying to use it.

Comment: Hmm, I don't need to `delete` the copy ctor. Just adding a throwing move ctor seems to work fine - which I thought would be the same as the implicitly defined move ctor in this case.

Comment: @TedLyngmo If you explicitly declare a move constructor, the copy constructor becomes deleted. If the compiler declares the move constructor, the copy constructor is not deleted.

Comment: If I had to summarize, storing objects with throwing moves in a vector causes it to copy to avoid exceptions (since vector move can't throw), but you can force it to use the throwing move by deleting the copy constructor. Did I understand that right?

Comment: @beary605 Yes. Normally you don't need to do this explicitly, for example, if your class directly has a `unique_ptr` member, the compiler will delete your copy constructor automatically. In certain cases like the one here, you must act to delete the copy constructor, otherwise there will be an invalid copy constructor that the vector tries to use.

Comment: Interesting, ok! I think I learned a bit more about copy constructors and move constructors today. Thank you for all the help!