# Cannot resize a vector when element has class member Boost Concurrent Queue

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am creating N objects and for each one, spawning a thread to run a class method. This class has Boost Concurrent Queue as a member. However, I am getting a compiler (GCC) error:

```
stl_uninitialized.h:137:72: error: static assertion failed: result type must be constructible from value type of input range
```

I have created a smaller-, self-contained example below. The error refers to `std::vector::resize()`:

```
#include <boost/thread/sync_bounded_queue.hpp>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

struct Test
{
    Test() :_queue(1){}

    // UPDATE Still get the problem after adding the below two lines
    Test(const Test&) = delete;
    Test(Test&&) = default;

    void hello(){}
    boost::concurrent::sync_bounded_queue<int> _queue;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Test> vec;
    vec.resize(10);         // The error is caused by this line
   
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        std::thread t(&Test::hello, &vec.at(i));
        t.join();
    }
}
```

The reason I use a vector is because because if I just create them on the stack (like below) I wasn't sure if the objects would live beyond the scope of the loop

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    Test test;
    std::thread t(&Test::hello, &test);
    t.join();
}
```

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64758775/3684343 ?

Comment: @mch It makes sense but unfortunately when I add those two "constructors" to Test I still get the compiler error.

Comment: `boost::concurrent::sync_bounded_queue<int>` is not a copyable or moveable object.

Comment: You can just use `std::vector<Test> vec(10);` instead of resize which would initialize value inplace

Comment: @dewaffled 10 was just an example. Unfortunately the size is not known at compile time.

Comment: @NathanOliver I require multiple instances, each with a Boost CQ class member. Are there any other ways to achieve this?

Comment: Sure, use `std::vector<Test> vec(my_runtime_size);` but do that once you know the run time value

Comment: Perhaps a different container such as std::list would help as it doesn't copy its elements around?

Comment: @NathanOliver Might as well put that as the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the Test structure inside a `unique_ptr`, which is fully moveable.  Since the Test structure itself might get quite complicated, and maybe also large, and since you have no other particular need for it to be moveable, it's not worth the trouble.

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Test>> vec;
   
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        vec.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Test>());
        std::thread t(&Test::hello, vec.back().get());
        // or std::thread t([&]{vec.back()->hello();});
        t.join();
    }
}
```

Or consider `shared_ptr` if your lifetime management gets more complicated.